# Windows Viruses Infected ext4 drive

Tags: linux, windows, virus, ext4

I have a drive thats formatted as ext4 and being used by my linux install. It recently got infected by some viruses and clamav is just pathetic as it asks to delete each file, something which i would really like to avoid if possible. I was wondering how would i use a windows antivirus to scan my disk thats ext4 formatted. I have got a spared old winxp box somewhere, i hope the antivirus there is still not over its free version.

Comment: How did you get infected in the first place? 
Is it a linux or a windows virus? 
Did you get rootkitted too?

Comment: I just copied some data that was infected and browse through it using windows vm so it effected other files in that location as well as share was mounted as rw in vbox.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try knoppicillin. A special Linux Distro based on Knoppix, containing several Antivirus tools.

http://www.heise.de/software/download/knoppicillin_download_edition/37894 (german language, though)

Or any of several antivirus linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with a Windows-based AV utility, then one possibility is to:

- mount the ext4 through Linux
- share it out via SMB (Samba)
- mount the share with a working Windows system
- scan with the Windows AV of your choice (as long as it supports scanning across network shares)